# How do you use a custom complete key sequence (C-space instead of Tab) in SuperTab for Vim?

Tags: plugins, autocomplete, vim

I started using SuperTab recently, but I want to use Ctrl-space *instead of* Tab.

My problem is that I often use Tab to add indentation inside comments, but SuperTab starts completion. I know I can use `Ctrl-V Tab`, but that's clumsy (especially since I don't use Tab for completion).

I tried adding this in my vimrc...

```
let g:SuperTabMappingForward = '<c-space>'
let g:SuperTabMappingBackward = '<s-c-space>'
```

...and that allows me to use C-space, but Tab still does autocomplete. I want to use Tab to  insert indentation and never completion.

I'm using [SuperTab continued](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1643).

---

I started using SuperTab because I want context-sensitive completion with [Eclim](http://eclim.org/) (Eclipse + Vim). I set this:

```
let g:SuperTabDefaultCompletionType = 'context'
```

And SuperTab switches between text completion and user-defined (eclim) completion (for member functions and variables) as appropriate. If there's a simpler way to do this, then that would be an acceptable solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Judging strictly from the documentation, you may be able to get this effect by also setting `g:SuperTabMappingTabLiteral` to `<Tab>`.

Edit: I was able to test this in gvim this morning with positive results.  Setting this setting in conjunction with the two mentioned in your post allowed me to insert literal tab characters with `<Tab>` and do completion with `<C-space>`.

Comment: Reading the doc for g:SuperTabMappingTabLiteral, that should solve my problem, but it doesn't. When I'm after a semicolon and hit tab, it starts completing again.

Comment: @pydave unfortunately I can't reproduce this.  I don't see why it shouldn't work though.  Maybe a bug in supertab?

Answer (score -1):

Had the same problem...

After looking in the documentation, it appears that `<C-Tab>` is what you're looking for.

Comment: To do what? Are you saying that I should use Ctrl-Tab instead of Tab for indenting?